# Exact matches in elastic index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

Let's say we have an index with a field "title"

There are documents in the index with values

"one"
"One two"
"One two three"
"One two three etc"

Is there a way to write a query which return documents with "one two" values only without "one two three ..."?

Also I need to be able to run full text searches against this field.

The only solution which I have in my mind is to have 2 separate columns for exact filtering - keyword type for "term" query and "text type" for full-text search with match query.

Am I right or there is a way to achieve both requirements (filtering and searching) with only one field?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a field as both `text` and `keyword`.

[Official reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#text-multi-fields)

Comment: Thanks, It's exactly what I need